# SQL Server 2014 compile Stored Procedure response

Tags: sql-server-2014, stored-procedures

I have several SQL Servers and databases and when I compile a Stored Procedure I receive one of two responses...

```
ALTER_PROCEDURE - dbo.usp_MyProcedure
```

or

```
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

My question is why did I receive different responses. The setting has to be at the server level somewhere, because every database on that server where I compile the SP I get the same message.  I received the alter message on 17 databases on 3 servers, and the command completed message on 19 databases on 7 servers.

I use Redgate's Multi Script to push the stored procedure at the same time, I know it is not in Multi Script due to compiling the SP using SSMS yields the sames responses.
Can anybody point me to the setting that controls this response?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik As I stated in my post, "I know it is not in Multi Script due to compiling the SP using SSMS yields the sames responses."

Comment: It looks like a DDL trigger that echos the DDL operations. It seems it's not installed on the other database.

Comment: @DanGuzman You are correct, I found a trigger from an old Source control that was doing this.  If you post your comment as an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a DDL trigger exists in some, but not all, of the databases. The trigger apparently uses a PRINT or RAISERROR statement to generate a message containing the DDL action and object name.